# Ошибка при использовании Compiled Bindings в Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Есть следующая xaml страница:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Test.ViewModels" 
         x:DataType="viewmodels:OrdersViewModel"
         x:Class="Test.Views.OrdersView" 
         Title="Мои заказы">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView"
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding MyOrders}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

В ней явно указан `DataType`, то есть используется Compiled Bindings. Она привязана к следующему классу:

```
public class OrdersViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<Order> MyOrders;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        InitializeOrders();
    }

    private async void InitializeOrders()
    {
        var list = await DataService.GetMyOrdersAsync();
        MyOrders = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
        list.ForEach(o => MyOrders.Add(o));
    }

}
```

Класс `Order`:

```
public class Order
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string HtmlContent { get; set; }

}
```

Метод `Initialize` вызывается в коде страницы:

```
public partial class OrdersView : ContentPage
{

    private OrdersViewModel context = new OrdersViewModel();
    public OrdersView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = context;

    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        context.Initialize();
    }

}
```

Но при компиляции возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Binding: Property "Title" not found on "Test.ViewModels.OrdersViewModel"
```

В чём может быть проблема? И как её решить?

Comment: Запомните одно правило, самое важное правило: Привязка возможна **только** к **публичным свойствам**!

Comment: Но свойство-то публичное.

Comment: Где вы здесь увидели **свойство** `public ObservableCollection<Order> MyOrders;`?

Comment: В классе OrdersViewModel.

Comment: Я вам выше скопировал строчку кода, это свойство или поле? У него есть `get;` и `set;`? Ели нету, то наверно это поле, а не нужное свойство? Еще раз повторю: привязка доступна **только** к **публичным свойствам**, не полям!

Comment: Ой. Как-то я и не заметил. Вы оказались правы. Но теперь возникла такая же ошибка, только связанная с Title. Я прикреплю к вопросу код класса Order.

Comment: Судя по показанному коду, ошибки быть не должно.

Comment: @aepot, увы, она возникает.

Comment: Почитайте внимательно ошибку, что там сказано? "Нет свойства `Title` в `OrdersViewModel`". Почему он у вас ищет там, а не в `Order`? Как сказали выше, в данном коде проблем нету, за исключением: `private OrdersViewModel context` - опять не свойство (но это не важно, но лучше сделать). `MyOrders = new ObservableCollection<Order>();` - если нет INPC, то интерфейс не узнает про изменения свойства. И да, если отредактировали вопрос, то исправляйте то, что уже решили, а лучше добавляйте ниже, а не изменяйте!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, у меня тот же вопрос. Почем он ищет в ViewModel, если в ItemsSource указана коллекция? Я полагал, что для ListView.DataTemplate контекстом привязки является именно коллекция ItemsSource в ListView, но похоже, что в данном случае оным является контекст привязки страницы. Или же я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, и ещё пару вопросов. Разве ObservableCollection не самодостаточен для того, чтобы не реализовывать INPC? И насчёт `private OrdersViewMode context`. Почему в данном случае лучше свойство, а не поле?

Comment: `ListView.DataTemplate контекстом привязки является именно коллекция ItemsSource в ListView` - я конечно с колокольни WPF вещаю, не знаю, мб в ксамарин это иначе, но в WPF идет строго Коллекция -> объекты, то есть вид каждого объекта контрола по типу `ItemsControl`, автоматически будет брать контестом тот объект, что лежит в привязанной коллекции. Пока я могу лишь предположить, что у вас есть еще некий код, который мне неизвестен.

Comment: `Разве ObservableCollection не самодостаточен` - самодостаточен в чем? В `.Add()`, да, он оповестит о том, что в нем были изменения, но вы же меняете свойство, а не элементы внутри коллекции. То есть, если вы делаете `MyOrders.Add()` (или любой другой метод), то все ок, если вы делаете `MyOrders = new();`, то свойство вы изменили, у вас другая коллекция, вам надо будет оповестить интерфейс о том, что в свойстве другая коллекция, а это INPC.